# Como utilizar um índice específico numa consulta em SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, índices, otimização

Tenho uma tabela não normalizada no SQL Server instalado em meu PC a qual é alimentada mensalmente pelo Integration Services (SSIS) a partir de um relatório numa planilha do Excel. Ou seja, estou mantendo o histórico de um certo relatório.

Esta tabela possui vários campos chave. Dependendo da consulta que quero fazer nesta tabela, quero que o SQL Server utilize um index específico.

Por exemplo, a tabela abaixo possui vários campos de identificação.

```
+---------------+---------+-------+
| Campo         | Tipo    | Index |
+---------------+---------+-------+
| DataID        | date    |   *   |
| NumFolhaID    | int     |   *   |
| LotacaoID     | int     |   *   |
| LotacaoNome   | varchar |       |
| LotacaoZona   | varchar |       |
| FuncMatricID  | int     |   *   |
| FuncVincID    | varchar |   *   |
| FuncNome      | varchar |       |
| FuncCpf       | varchar |       |
| CargoCarreira | varchar |       |
| CargoNome     | varchar |       |
| FuncaoNome    | varchar |       |
| Remuneracao   | money   |       |
| DataAdm       | date    |       |
+---------------+---------+-------+
```

Eu criei três índices:

- `INDEX_FUNC` - composto pelos campos (`FuncMatricID`, `FuncVincID`, `DataID`) nesta ordem;
- `INDEX_LOTA` - composto pelos campos (`LotacaoID`, `DataID`, `FuncVincID`) nesta ordem;
- `INDEX_FOLH` - composto pelos campos (`DataID`, `NumFolhaID`) nesta ordem;

Ao utilizar um SELECT gostaria de utilizar um índice específico para a consulta.

Comment: Desculpe, não sei se trata-se de uma particularidade do SQL Server, mas não consegui entender exatamente em que ponto você está precisando de ajuda.

Comment: Para mim também não ficou muito claro...

Comment: Ao utilizar um SELECT gostaria de utilizar um índice específico, com o intuito de otimizar a busca. Pois, se o índice está na ordem do INDEX_FUNC, quando eu uso uma consulta que some o total do campo `Remuneracao` por `LotacaoID`, a consulta simplesmente fica lenta, pois os campos estão indexados por outros campos que não fazem parte da estratégia da consulta.

Comment: Forçar determinado índice nunca é bom...

Comment: Geralmente o compilador de consulta do sql server seleciona o melhor índice para acessar cada tabela, bem como qual o método de acesso. Para isso considera várias informações que ele mantém sobre as tabelas.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Você pode executar a consulta como abaixo:

```sql
SELECT CAMPO
FROM TABELA WITH (INDEX(INDEX_LOTA))
```

E também é possível adicionar INDEX em um join

```sql
SELECT CAMPO
FROM TABELA T WITH (INDEX(INDEX_LOTA))
INNER JOIN OUTRA_TABELA OT
WITH (INDEX(OUTRO_INDICE))
ON OT.ID = T.ID
```

Comment: Opa, estou quebrando a cabeça aqui com mysql, preciso selecionar vários registros sem que o script passe mais de 1 vez pelo mesmo nome de usuário ou ID, estou usando Index na query porém me retorna 1 registro só, preciso que a cada f5 ele me retorne outro diferente.