# Como aplicar indexes para melhorar a performance das queries?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, desempenho, índices

Estou querendo aumentar a performance de meu banco de dados, que tem mais de 1 milhão de registros.

#### Pesquisas que realizei

- Sobre index [link1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/524/como-utilizar-um-%C3%ADndice-espec%C3%ADfico-numa-consulta-em-sql-server/525#525)
- Sobre cluster [link1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38343/filtros-ou-ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o-qual-deve-ser-o-primeiro-ao-criar-um-%C3%ADndice-no-banco-de-da/38388#38388) [link2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38343/filtros-ou-ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o-qual-deve-ser-o-primeiro-ao-criar-um-%C3%ADndice-no-banco-de-da/38388#38388)

#### Dúvida

A ideia do *cluster* me pareceu muito tentadora, mas parece uma medida um tanto drástica, e desnecessária. Então preferiria permanecer com *index*, só que tenho uma dúvida:

- Faz sentido ter mais de uma coluna em um *index*? As outras colunas não teriam de percorrer todos os registros de qualquer jeito por não ser a principal?

#### Exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_item(
    cd_item integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tb_item_cd_item_seq'::regclass),
    ds_item character varying(30),
    CONSTRAINT pktb_item PRIMARY KEY (cd_item)
);

CREATE INDEX "tb_item_cd_item_Idx" ON tb_item (cd_item, ds_item);

SELECT
    cd_item
FROM
    tb_item
WHERE
    ds_item ILIKE 'B%';
```

Mesmo eu estando buscando por `ds_item ILIKE 'B%';` ao meu ver ele teria de percorrer a tabela inteira, já que que o item de `cd_item = 570000` pode ter `ds_item = 'bola'`.

Neste caso seria melhor fazer isso?:

`CREATE INDEX "tb_item_ds_item_Idx" ON tb_item (ds_item);`

Em resumo a minha pergunta é:

É mais aproveitável a cada `SELECT` criar um *`INDEX`* com a coluna principal, ou ter um
*`INDEX`* com todas as colunas principais?

Comment: Agora que eu vi que uma recompensa foi colocada. O que aconteceu com ela? Mesmo que não fosse dada manualmente, eu acho que eu receberia 50%.

Comment: @bigown Aqui não aparece, mas eu tinha posto como "uma ou mais respostas...", e achei que entraria automático, pois isso não coloquei manualmente. Creio que tenha que ver com o Gabi.

Comment: Perguntei no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4794/101

Comment: Guilherme, as recompensas devem ser atribuídas manualmente. A atribuição automática existe apenas em determinados casos, dadas certas condições.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Índice *clusterizado*

Não sei se você entendeu o termo *clustered index*, imagino que você está pensando em índices espalhados por máquinas em nós de *cluster*, não é isto.

Este é um termo usado para indicar que o índice é a própria tabela de dados. Ou seja, os dados da tabela são gravados na ordem deste índice, então a própria tabela é usada como índice. Isto tem vantagens e desvantagens, mas em geral as vantagens superam as desvantagens. Obviamente os índices não *clusterizados* são aqueles que precisam de uma estrutura auxiliar para armazenar na ordem desejada. Usando a lógica fica claro que uma tabela só pode ter **um** índice *clusterizado*.

Para saber mais pode ler o [artigo da Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Clustered) ou a [documentação do SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15) que implementa esta técnica de forma mais explícita.

Então não há nenhum exagero nisso, pelo contrário, esta prática é a mais comum quando o banco de dados a oferece.

## Índice multicolunar

É extremamente comum ter várias colunas em um índice, sempre que exista algum motivo para acessar os dados na ordem composta de mais de uma coluna, isto deve ser feito.

Lembrando que você não precisa usar todas as colunas de cada índice nas suas buscas. Claro que o índice só poderá ser utilizado com eficácia se na busca constar por inteiro as primeiras colunas. Então você buscar só pela primeira coluna utiliza o índice. Buscar só pela segunda coluna não tem como utilizá-lo. Aí a solução é ter um outro índice com a segunda coluna deste como a primeira de outro índice.

Índices para usar com `LIKE` podem funcionar bem quando você tem um texto seguido de `%`, mas se tiver um texto depois do símbolo `%`, o índice não poderá ajudar. É o mesmo princípio explicado acima, é uma quebra da sequência de busca.

Pense num dicionário como o Aurélio, você acha as palavras facilmente, certo? Porque as palavras estão em um índice *clusterizado*. Você sabe a ordem e sabe que pode fazer uma busca semelhante à [busca binária](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesquisa_bin%C3%A1ria). Mas se você souber apenas o fim da palavra, você consegue fazer esta busca eficientemente?

Claro que colocar colunas adicionais só por colocar não vai ajudar nada. Tem que ter critério. Tem que entender esse processo de que no fundo quando você cria um índice com várias colunas está criando uma palavra enorme que faz sentido se estiver naquela ordem. E se você procurar binariamente ela possa ser encontrada facilmente. A busca funciona bem enquanto você tiver uma sequência de dados organizados logicamente.

Colocar colunas que não podem ser aproveitadas na ordem descrita no índice em nenhum tipo de *query* expressiva que será usada só fará consumir espaço no índice, é um contrassenso.

Não é fácil determinar isso sem ver o caso específico. Mesmo que possa ser útil para uma *query*, pode ser desnecessário. Em alguns casos o ganho pode ser muito pequeno para compensar. Ter experiência ajuda determinar isso. Mas pode atrapalhar. O jeito certo é testar. Ver se todas situações funciona bem com ou sem índice. Então a melhor resposta que posso te dar para o principal da sua pergunta é: **teste**. Veja se as *queries* se beneficiam do índice.

Claro que no começo você perderá tempo com índices que ajudam em nada ou mesmo atrapalham. Se você for profissional, na melhor acepção da palavra, o tempo fará você selecionar melhor e evitar os testes desnecessários sem deixar de lado os que podem trazer resultados importantes. Mas sem testar nem mesmo os gênios da indexação de banco de dados podem garantir o que funciona bem em situações específicas.

E tenha em mente que o que é bom em um momento pode não ser mais no futuro. As *queries* podem mudar, a carga de utilização de cada uma muda, o padrão de dados pode fazer um índice bom ser ruim e e vice-versa. **Não tem regra mágica**.

Quando você tem um índice com `UNIQUE` é um pouco mais difícil ter utilidade usar outras colunas depois da coluna com restrição de unicidade.

Note que algumas pessoas acham que colocar todas colunas em um índice ou criar um índice para cada coluna resolve todas situações. Além disto ser um desperdício óbvio, não resolve todas situações (e nem deveria, só deve resolver o que será necessário e vai produzir resultados eficientes de verdade). É virtualmente impossível tratar todas as combinações (a não ser com 2 ou 3 campos) já que as *queries* podem estar procurando por dados de forma parcial ou manipulada de alguma forma. Mesmo que restrinja as soluções possíveis só à colunas completas não é fácil combinar todas colunas a não ser que exista pouco mais de 2 ou 3 colunas.

Já escrevi sobre isso em algumas respostas sobre [as vantagens e desvantagens dos índices](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/101), o [abuso de índices](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23348/101) e um [caso específico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32052/101) que parecia que o índice ajudaria mas os testes mostraram que não.

## Seu exemplo

Me parece que seria útil ter o `CREATE INDEX "tb_item_ds_item_Idx" ON tb_item (ds_item);`. Certeza eu só dou testando no caso real, vendo em produção o que acontece.

Se ele deve ser adicional ao outro que você já deve ter com duas colunas eu não posso garantir. Aí precisaria ver se há utilidade em outras *queries* para o índice `(cd_item, ds_item)` Nesta *query* mostrada ele não serve. E me parece que qualquer índice que utilize `cd_item` não se beneficiará de colunas depois dela, pelo menos não diretamente.

Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.