# Performance da query - Postgresql

Tags: sql, query, desempenho, postgresql

Tenho a seguinte situação, preciso trazer dados de um tabela veiculo do sistema em que trabalho e outra com dados integrados de um sistema parceiro, por ser integração os dados não são muito consistentes e a forma de ligar as tabelas pode ser por chassi, placa ou id:

```
select COUNT(*) from syo_veiculo = 290518
select COUNT(*) from syo_oficina = 945336

select vei.id_veiculo, vei.id_cliente, vei.id_empresa, ofi.no_os, ofi.dt_emissao, ofi.id_empresa as empresaofi

from syo_veiculo vei
 join syo_oficina ofi ON vei.id_veiculo = ofi.id_produto OR vei.ds_placa = ofi.ds_placa OR vei.no_chassi = ofi.no_chassi

where vei.dt_venda BETWEEN 1435100000000 AND 1435900000000
group by vei.id_veiculo, vei.id_cliente, vei.id_empresa, ofi.no_os, ofi.dt_emissao, empresaofi

= 879 linhas em 30622 ms, 30337 ms, 30275 ms
```

Note que o resultado da query foi obtido em cerca de 30 segundos, sem agrupamento, traria 1078 linhas no mesmo tempo.

Query alternativa:

```
select *
from (
    select vei.id_veiculo, vei.id_cliente, vei.id_empresa, ofi.no_os, ofi.dt_emissao, ofi.id_empresa as empresaofi

    from syo_veiculo vei
     join syo_oficina ofi ON vei.id_veiculo = ofi.id_produto

    where vei.dt_venda BETWEEN 1435100000000 AND 1435900000000

    union all

    select vei.id_veiculo, vei.id_cliente, vei.id_empresa, ofi.no_os, ofi.dt_emissao, ofi.id_empresa as empresaofi

    from syo_veiculo vei
     join syo_oficina ofi ON vei.ds_placa = ofi.ds_placa

    where vei.dt_venda BETWEEN 1435100000000 AND 1435900000000

    union all

    select vei.id_veiculo, vei.id_cliente, vei.id_empresa, ofi.no_os, ofi.dt_emissao, ofi.id_empresa as empresaofi

    from syo_veiculo vei
     join syo_oficina ofi ON vei.no_chassi = ofi.no_chassi

    where vei.dt_venda BETWEEN 1435100000000 AND 1435900000000
) as tbaux
group by id_veiculo, no_os, id_cliente, id_empresa, dt_emissao, empresaofi

= 879 linhas em 1969 ms, 791 ms, 724 ms
```

Note que o retorno veio muito mais rápido, as mesmas 879 linhas sem o agrupamento traria 2172 linhas no mesmo tempo.

- Quero entender por que a query com os `union all` onde tem muito mais validações leva bem menos tempo, não faz sentido para mim, ainda mais que o resultado foi o mesmo
- Existe algum exceção nestes casos `union all X join com OR`, por exemplo uma FK na tabela oficina poderia fazer alguma diferença a favor do `join` ?

Quero enteder o por que disto para planejar melhor minhas próximas queries e buscar o melhor desempenho.

Comment: você tem índices para estas três colunas nos dois bancos?

Comment: @TobyMosque Não tem indices entre as tabelas.

Comment: Você não pode esperar muito ao realizar um join entre duas tabelas quando nenhuma das tabelas tem indices, ainda acho 2s muito tempo para o retorno de 800 linhas.

Comment: @TobyMosque 2 segundos apenas na primeira execução o que é comum, o banco guarda informações da query excutada para agilizar nas consultas posteriores, 790 ms não é ruim sendo que as tabelas tem 290 mil e 940 mil linhas cada, independente do numero de linhas no retorno cada linha de cada tabela foi verificada.

Comment: @TobyMosque você acha que os indices são únicos responsáveis ou tem mais algum fator ?

Comment: acredito que seja apenas os indices, realizar um tablescan em uma tabela com milhares de registros é bastante custoso.

Comment: @TobyMosque Esta situação dos indices está fora do meu controle pois não posso alterar o banco deste sistema, vou fazer alguns testes com um banco teste e devolver o resultado quando possível, desde já obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: eu lhe entendo, já passei por uma situação parecida, no meu caso acabei tendo que usar uma tabela em memoria

Comment: Execute um EXPLAIN ANALYZE [SUA QUERY]; em cada uma das suas queries da pergunta e adicione os resultados na pergunta para que eu possa analisar e te ajudar.

Comment: @TobyMosque Já existia indices em placa, chassi das tabelas e **id_veiculo** é chave primaria, incluí um index para **ofi.id_produto** e o tempo da primeira query caiu para 111 millisegundos, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: o index - ```create index oficina_id_produto_idx on syo_oficina using hash(id_produto);``` resolveu o problema.

Comment: Seria preciso ver o plano de execução das duas consultas utilizando o comando EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Comment: Relacionado : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55118/como-aplicar-indexes-para-melhorar-a-performance-das-queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
    WITH tbaux  AS
    ( select vei.id_veiculo, vei.id_cliente, vei.id_empresa, ofi.no_os, ofi.dt_emissao, ofi.id_empresa as empresaofi
        from syo_veiculo vei
        join syo_oficina ofi ON vei.id_veiculo = ofi.id_produto
        where vei.dt_venda BETWEEN 1435100000000 AND 1435900000000

        union all

        select vei.id_veiculo, vei.id_cliente, vei.id_empresa, ofi.no_os, ofi.dt_emissao, ofi.id_empresa as empresaofi

        from syo_veiculo vei
        join syo_oficina ofi ON vei.ds_placa = ofi.ds_placa
        where vei.dt_venda BETWEEN 1435100000000 AND 1435900000000

        union all

        select vei.id_veiculo, vei.id_cliente, vei.id_empresa, ofi.no_os, ofi.dt_emissao, ofi.id_empresa as empresaofi
        from syo_veiculo vei
        join syo_oficina ofi ON vei.no_chassi = ofi.no_chassi

        where vei.dt_venda BETWEEN 1435100000000 AND 1435900000000)
SELECT * FROM tbaux group by id_veiculo, no_os, id_cliente, id_empresa, dt_emissao, empresaofi;
```

É interessante também você verificar os índices das tabelas.
Você também pode rodar algumas rotinas de manutenção do banco (Vacuum Analise, REIDEX e CLUSTER).

Porém, vale lembrar que é recomendado que o vacuum seja feito em um horário que o banco não esteja sendo utilizado..

Comment: Estava revendo estas perguntas que fiz no passado, até para dar um fim nelas, o problema da sua query é que no software que uso para geração de relatórios, ele não permite iniciar a query com with, o problema era mesmo um índice que faltava em ds_placa.