# Qual a necessidade de informar o parâmetro "Order" no objeto do tipo IndexAnnotation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-api

Estou criando índices para algumas colunas que serão utilizadas numa consulta com `Where()`. O intuito é deixar a pesquisa mais rápida. Até então estava criando assim:

```
Property(x => x.Documento)
            .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
                                 new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("ix_documento", 1) { IsUnique = false }));

Property(x => x.Vencimento)
            .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
                                 new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("ix_vencimento", 2) { IsUnique = false }));
```

Porém notei que a classe `IndexAttribute` tem um construtor que aceita apenas o nome do índice.

A descrição do parâmetro `order` é:

> order: A number which will be used to determine column ordering for multi-column indexes.

Seria algo assim:

> Um número que será usado para determinar ordenação de coluna para
>   indíces multi-colunas

Não entendi isso, e se no meu caso faz alguma diferença ou não.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Antes de tudo, vamos pegar a descrição exata da propriedade [IndexAttribute.Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute.order(v=vs.113).aspx).

> Obtém ou define um número que determina a ordenação de coluna para índices de várias colunas. Isso será -1 se nenhuma ordem de coluna tiver sido especificada.
>
> **Observações**
> Os índices de várias colunas são criados usando o mesmo nome de índice em vários atributos. As informações nesses atributos são então mescladas em conjunto para especificar o índice do banco de dados real.

Em resumo, você utilizará a propriedade `Order` quando possuir um Índice para várias colunas com o mesmo nome.

Veja este exemplo (com DataAnnotations para ser mais simples de entender) da [própria Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Index) para entender melhor como utilizar:

```
public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        [Index("IX_BlogIdAndRating", 2)]
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        [Index("IX_BlogIdAndRating", 1)]
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
    }
```

Note que as propriedades `Rating` e `BlogId` possuem o mesmo índice, onde a primeira coluna é `BlogId`, por causa da ordem 1.

Para o seu exemplo específico, não há necessidade de adicionar a ordem, pois os índices são diferentes. E como dito na pergunta, você deseja apenas com o intuito de deixar a consulta "mais rápida".

Caso queira saber mais sobre Índices, [veja esta pergunta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55118/20615)

Comment: Resposta com maiores detalhes sobre Índice de várias colunas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55137/26552

Comment: @Murilo Eu procurei alguma referência aqui no site, mas não havia encontrado. Vou adicionar na resposta, obrigado.