# Demora para contar registros na primeira vez

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, índices, sql-server-2014

Estou fazendo um teste de estresse em uma aplicação que estou desenvolvendo. Adicionei alguns milhões de registros numa tabela, que é o que ela terá em cerca de 5 anos de uso. Eu utilizo Entity Framework. Ao fazer a contagem de registros de uma *query*, demorou bastante para ocorrer. Achei que era problema do EF. Porém ao fazer um trace no SQL Server e rodar a consulta diretamente no banco de dados notei que a demora é no próprio SQL Server.

Olhem a seguinte *query* de exemplo, parecida com a gerada pelo EF, porém bem mais simples e ainda demora bastante:

```
select count(1) from tbMovimentoConta where con_codigo_fk = 1 and mcon_data >= '2017-01-01' and mcon_data <= '2018-01-01'
```

Resultado: 1.162.158 registros

Tempo: 24 segundos

Ao repetir a consulta é instantâneo, creio que por causa do cache. Porém se limpar o cache com o comando `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` irá demorar cerca de 25 segundos novamente.

O campo `con_codigo_fk` utilizado no `where` da consulta acima é uma chave estrangeira e possui índice.

O campo `mcon_data` também usado no `where` da consulta acima possui índice também.

Essa tabela possuí mais 4 índices de chaves estrangeiras, e mais dois índices para os campos `mcon_dataExclusao` e `mcon_dataInclusao` que são utilizados em pesquisas.

*Script* do índice da coluna `mcon_data` para analisarem e apontarem alguma possível falha no mesmo.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_mcon_data] ON [dbo].[tbMovimentoConta]
(
    [mcon_data] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

É normal essa demora para essa quantidade de registros? Não me parece tão grande assim. Não sei se é a quantidade de índices, ou a forma que os mesmos foram criados. Estou investigando.

Configuração do computador: 8GB de RAM e Core I7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sem um registro adequado é normal. e precisa que seja feito rápido então crie um índice para isto. Provavelmente vai resolver se usar `con_codigo_fk` e `mcon_data` na chave.

```
CREATE INDEX [ix__con_codigo_fk__mcon_data]
    ON [dbo].[tbMovimentoConta] ([con_codigo_fk], [mcon_data]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/Index2.sql).

Leia também:

- [Quais as vantagens e desvantagens do uso de índices em base de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/101)
- [Como aplicar indexes para melhorar a performance das queries?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55118/101)

Comment: Não entendi "Sem um registro adequado é normal".

Comment: Você não perguntou se é normal ser lento? Índices fazem toda diferença, se não tiver um adequado, é normal ser lento.

Comment: Então. Índices tem, mas pelo jeito não estão ajudando. Estou estudando as outras respostas pra ver se dá uma luz. É um assunto complexo. Essa tabela tem uma PK que é auto-incremento. Vou tentar adicionar os outros campos na chave então. Nessas horas falta uma especialização em DBA.

Comment: Na sua pergunta não mostra. Se não estão ajudando eles são inadequados, conforme eu falei.

Answer (score 1):

Como o @Maniero disse, tinha algo errado com os índices atuais. Pesquisando sobre, e recorrendo a ajuda em outro [site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160098/reducing-the-duration-of-this-count-query) da rede, cheguei a solução.

A solução foi criar um índice composto para as colunas `mcon_data` e `con_codigo_fk`

```
CREATE INDEX ix__con_codigo_fk__mcon_data
ON dbo.tbMovimentoConta
(con_codigo_fk, mcon_data) ;
```

Após a criação desse índice, a consulta é tão rápida, que não chega a dar um segundo (o meu Management Studio não mostra os milissegundos).

Comment: Ou seja, fez exatamente o que eu respondi :)

Comment: É. Edita, posta o código de criação que aceito a sua com maior prazer, pois você falou de usar na chave, acho que isso me confundiu, estava pensando em chave(PK).

Comment: Inclusive removo a minha.

Comment: Nem acho que é caso pra remover. Índices são criado através de chaves. O que você configura nele são chaves.

Comment: "user26552", sobre o teste de estresse; contar linhas não ajuda muito pois não há recuperação de informação. Um índice pode ser útil para contar linhas mas completamente inútil para acessar a tabela.