# Melhorar desempenho de consulta lenta em MS SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, desempenho, índices, sql-server-2014

Os índices estão incorretos?

Estou com dificuldades em otimizar uma consulta. Havia feito [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175344/demora-para-contar-registros-na-primeira-vez) para um caso mais simples que resolveu, mas para esse caso não estou conseguindo um resultado melhor.  A seguinte consulta está levando 19 segundos:

```
select top 12
c.crec_codigo_pk, -- bigint
c.crec_dataInclusao, -- datetime
c.crec_dataVencimento, -- datetime
c.crec_dataPagamento, -- datetime
c.crec_restanteFinal, -- decimal
c.crec_valorPrincipal, -- decimal
c.crec_multaRestante, -- decimal
c.crec_jurosRestante, -- decimal
c.crec_acrescimoRestante, -- decimal
c.crec_desconto -- decimal
from tbContaReceber c
-- crec_isMovimentoConta  é bit
where crec_isMovimentoConta = 0 and crec_dataExclusao is null and
      crec_dataVencimento >= '2015-01-01' and crec_dataVencimento <= '2016-01-01' and
      crec_restanteFinal = 0 and pes_codigo_fk = 834
```

Essa consulta irá buscar por contas a receber de um período, filtrando as que não foram excluídas, bem como as que são do tipo "movimento de conta", que não tenham valor restante, filtrando as contas de um cliente/fornecedor específico.

Indíce:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_consulta_1] ON [dbo].[tbContaReceber]
(
    [crec_isMovimentoConta] ASC,
    [crec_dataExclusao] ASC,
    [crec_dataVencimento] ASC,
    [crec_restanteFinal] ASC,
    [pes_codigo_fk] ASC,
    [fpag_codigo_fk] ASC,
    [crec_documento] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   
    [crec_codigo_pk],
    [crec_dataInclusao],
    [crec_dataPagamento],
    [crec_valorPrincipal],
    [crec_multaRestante],
    [crec_jurosRestante],
    [crec_acrescimoRestante],
    [crec_desconto]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Observações que podem ser úteis:

- há um pouco mais de 5 milhões de registros na tabela
- essa tabela tem mais campos (cerca de 50)
- a maioria dos registros crec_dataExclusao terá valor nulo - nessa base de testes 100%
- nesse teste 100% dos registros de `crec_isMovimentoConta` são valor "0". Em produção será cera de 50%.
- o campo `pes_codigo_fk` tem cerca de 1894 valores distintos distribuídos pros 5 milhões de registros.
- poderá ainda ter mais dois critérios de consulta, mas nem coloquei eles ainda no where e está levando 19 segundos
- essa demora ocorre na primeira consulta. Porém se reiniciar o server, ou rodar `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` irá demorar a próxima consulta.

Realmente não sei se é falha de estruturação desse banco, culpa de dados repetidos, ou falha nos índice mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenta alterar a cláusula `where` para o exemplo abaixo. Checa se melhora alguma coisa:

```
where 
pes_codigo_fk = 834
and crec_dataVencimento BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01' 
and crec_dataExclusao is null 
and crec_isMovimentoConta = 0 
and crec_restanteFinal = 0
```

Além disso, crie um novo item com os campos utilizados na cláusula acima, na ordem em que se encontram.

Comment: Tenta alterar a ordem dos índices para corresponder às que estão na query que eu fiz.

Comment: Não sei se posso mudar essa ordem. Pois o código da pessoa nem sempre será informado, a data sim. Movendo a ordem do índice, se não informar a pessoa, creio que inutiliza o índice.

Comment: Pode criar outro índice com os campos acima, assim não comprometeria o outro.

Comment: Não foi informando o BD mas as Estatísticas de Banco estão atualizadas ?

Comment: @AllanAndrade ficou bem rápido dessa forma, ajudou bastante, embora tenha modificado um pouco a lógica inicial, mas me deu uma luz. O ideal era ficar rápido da outra forma, mas não sei se será possível.