# Qual a diferença entre clustered index e nonclustered index?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Estudando sobre encontrei um *[exemplo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18528/performance-difference-between-clustered-and-non-clustered-index)*, e sobre clustered diz:

> **Primary Keys** por padrão usam um indice agrupado (*clustered*), ou seja, ao realizar uma consulta `select * from myTable where IDColumn = 1` , o banco irá fazer uma busca binária para encontrar esse elemento,  em vez de uma varredura linha a linha.

Gostaria de uma opinião mais detalhada sobre o assunto, *se possível com planos de consulta ou com exemplos na prática.*

- *Qual a diferença entre clustered  index e nonclustered index?*
- *Em que ocasiões devo usar um e outro?*
- *Posso dizer que um índice agrupado é realizado uma [consulta binária](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesquisa_bin%C3%A1ria), e um índice não agrupado é usado uma consulta com [Árvore B](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_B)?*

**Nota**: Meu inglês não é muito bom, a pergunta que linquei acima me ajudou um pouco, mas não muito. Achei bem interessante os planos de consulta que o banco faz, até então desconhecidos.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55118/como-aplicar-indexes-para-melhorar-a-performance-das-queries

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Qual a diferença entre *clustered index* e *nonclustered index*?

O índice *clusterizado* é quase um sinônimo de chave primária. De fato só pode usar um por tabela e tem que ser na ordem da inserção dos dados, o que obviamente exclui [chaves primárias naturais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277091/101). Em um índice assim a chave é a posição onde o dado está. Na verdade **ele é a própria tabela**.

A chave primária está obviamente em ordem, assim possibilitando a pesquisa binária que é muito importante para dar performance.

O índice não *clusterizado* são todos os outros índices onde você terá uma chave qualquer e um apontador para a tabela de dados. Então há sempre duas pesquisas, uma no índice *non-cluster* e depois sabendo qual a posição dele buscará o dado de fato na tabela, que até pode ser um índice *clusterizado*.

Um índice não *clusterizado* tem as chaves em ordem também e pode fazer pesquisa binária da mesma forma.

> Em que ocasiões devo usar um e outro?

Então não tem muito segredo na escolha: chave primária quase sempre é o *clusterizado*, e não tem como outros índices serem *clusterizados*.

É importante notar que não é obrigatório o uso de índice *clusterizado*. Mesmo a chave primária pode usar uma chave normal que apontará para a tabela de dados.

Tem banco de dados (SQL Server) que permite o uso de chave natural *clusterizada*. O SQL Server nem exige que a chave primária seja única porque ele garante unicidade com algum custo extra. No SQL Server a única diferença entre ambos é a garantia da presença de todas colunas no *cluterizado*, ele é uma árvore binária comum. Há controvérsias se isso é um índice *clusterizado*. Minha teoria é que inicialmente era *clusterizado*, depois acharam melhor fazer a tabela ser ordenada de toda forma, mudaram o conceito mas não a terminologia. Por isso tem que tomar cuidado em se valer de detalhes de implementação para definir alguma coisa.

Como otimização um índice não *clusterizado* pode contar com algumas colunas extras se aquela pesquisa normalmente só precisa acessar algumas colunas específicas, eliminando a necessidade de busca na tabela de dados. Isso funciona em casos bem pensados. Nada impede de todos os índices terem todas colunas e assim qualquer *query* pode ser feita sem precisar ir na tabela de dados, mas do ponto de vista de espaço e de atualização dos dados isso é insano.

O mais comum é que os índices sejam armazenadas em alguma forma de estrutura de árvore binária (tem várias), mas isto não é obrigatório. O índice *clusterizado* pode usar um árvore simplificada ou até mesmo não ter uma árvore já que só pode fazer *append* na tabela e nunca mudará a ordem. Isto é uma detalhe de implementação.

> Posso dizer que um índice agrupado é realizado uma consulta binária, e um índice não agrupado é usado uma consulta com Árvore B?

A consulta ser binária nada tem a ver com a estrutura dos dados, a não ser pelo fato que esta estrutura precisa obrigatoriamente estar classificada.

Uma estrutura de árvore é útil para facilitar as inserções em qualquer ordem ou de forma distribuída por vários pontos da estrutura possibilitando rapidez em todo tipo de operação.

Entenda que a criação do índice *clusterizado* não cria nenhuma estrutura extra, apenas estabelece a forma de armazenar a tabela.

## Conclusão

Para uso geral acho que é suficiente saber isso. Detalhes só serão úteis para quem vai implementar um banco de dados ou que precisa entender os *internals* de um DB para algo muito fora da utilização normal.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Bacana a resposta, fiquei com algumas dúvidas @bigown! Posso dizer que faz sentido eu difinir uma `FK` como indice clusterizado, pelo fato de ela estar ordenada e ser aplicável a busca binaria? No seu 3º Paragrafo você quiz dizer que primeiro é realizado um indice não clusterizado para depois ser realizado um indice clusterizado?

Comment: A FK você definirá uma coluna que tem um dado que poderá fazer a busca em um índice *clusterizado*, ou não. Na verdade importa pouco. O ideal é que a FK busque em uma chave primária, como ela foi armazenada pouco importa para essa tabela que tem essa FK. Eu disse no 3o. parágrafo o que está escrito lá, que a busca é feita no índice não *clusterizado* para achar o que está sendo buscado (a chave), aí ele pega o valor dessa chave, no caso o apontador para o índice *clusterizado* e faz uma busca lá naquele índice. A forma como você escreveu não faz sentido pra mim.

Answer (score 10):

Marconi, o exemplo que você cita trata especificamente de SQL Server.

> *Qual a diferença entre clustered index e nonclustered index?*

A diferença básica entre índice *clustered* (agrupado) e *nonclustered* (não agrupado) é que, nos índices *clustered*, a estrutura do índice e os dados estão no mesmo arquivo; por isso o termo *clustered* (agrupado). São duas estruturas implementadas no mesmo arquivo. E, no caso dos índices *nonclustered*, estes não estão agrupados com os dados, isto é, estão em arquivos separados.

No SQL Server os índices (tanto *clustered* quanto *nonclustered*) são implementados utilizando [árvore B+](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_B%2B). A pesquisa direta (*seek*) é feita *caminhando* na árvore, até chegar a um nodo folha. No caso de leitura sequencial (*scan*), ocorre diretamente no nível folha, pois há uma lista duplamente encadeada nesse nível. Se o índice for do tipo *clustered*, os dados estão no nodo folha. Se for do tipo *nonclustered*, há um ponteiro (*row locator*) indicando onde estão os dados, na tabela.

Nos índices *clustered* as linhas são mantidas ordenadas logicamente. Para compreender a implementação, sugiro a leitura do item `Table and Items Structures`, páginas 188 a 197, do livro [`Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008: T-SQL Querying`](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/), de Itzik Ben-Gan.

---

> *Em que ocasiões devo usar um e outro?*

Para essa pergunta não há uma resposta única, pois depende do contexto e, principalmente, é necessário compreender os conceitos de chave natural, chave primária, chave substituta etc. Essa conceituação você encontra no artigo [Primary Key Primer for SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/primary-key-primer-for-sql-server/), de Phil Factor.

Conforme o artigo anteriormente mencionado, chave primária e índice *clustered* são coisas diferentes. Uma chave primária é uma construção lógica e um índice *clustered* é um índice com uma implementação física especial. Ao definir índice *clustered* para uma chave, você determina a forma como a chave é implementada.

E o autor salienta ainda que a escolha do índice *clustered* pode ter um forte impacto na performance. A chave candidata que faz  sentido como uma chave   primária pode não ter as características que são requeridas para um índice *clustered* com bom desempenho. Um bom índice *clustered* é leve e fácil de realizar comparações com ele. Uma boa chave primária nem sempre é assim.

Embora por padrão (*default*) no SQL Server as chaves primárias sejam implementadas utilizando índice do tipo *clustered*, isto não é obrigatório. Pode-se implementar chave primária usando índice *nonclustered*. Ou mesmo nem ter índice para a chave primária, mas somente uma declaração de unicidade (*unique*).

A escolha de índice *clustered* ou *nonclustered* depende do contexto. As seguintes tarefas compõem a estratégia recomendada para criação de índices:

- Entenda as características do banco de dados;
- Entenda as características das consultas mais usadas;
- Entenda as características das colunas usadas nas consultas;
- Determine quais opções de índice poderiam aumentar o desempenho na
  criação ou manutenção do índice;
- Determine o melhor local de armazenamento para o índice.

---

> *Posso dizer que um índice agrupado é realizado uma consulta binária, e um índice não agrupado é usado uma consulta com Árvore B?*

Pela resposta inicial, já sabe que não há nenhuma relação.

---

Conforme [Guia de criação de índice do SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj835095.aspx), um índice é uma estrutura em disco associada a uma tabela, que agiliza a recuperação das linhas. Um índice contém chaves criadas de uma ou mais colunas da tabela. Essas chaves são armazenadas em uma estrutura (árvore B) que habilita o SQL Server a localizar a linha ou as linhas associadas aos valores de chave de forma rápida e eficaz.

No documento [Índices clusterizados e não clusterizados descritos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190457.aspx) consta que índices agrupados classificam e armazenam as linhas de dados da tabela com base em seus valores de chave.

---

Comment: Duas sugestões de melhoria: explicar a diferença entre índices clusterizado e não-clusterizado; e acrescentar na resposta as partes essenciais dos links fornecidos, para que a resposta não seja invalidada caso os links saiam do ar (política do stackoverflow).

Comment: Obrigado pela respsota @JoséDiz  Vou dedicar um tempo a estes artigos, pois estou precisando! :)