# Uma View é mais rápida do que uma Query comum?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quando utilizo uma consulta do tipo

```
SELECT * FROM myView
```

é mais rápido do que

```
SELECT * FROM (query para gerar a view acima)
```

Tenho uma consulta e gostaria de cachear ou deixa-la mais rápida, porem estou em dúvidas se crio com *View* ou *Query* normal!

Comment: eu só trabalharia com view, se a query tiver que ser sempre daquela forma, caso você tenha que usar a view, e junto com uma sintaxe where o desempenho fica uma m... se o problema é só desempenho, nao acho que seja adequado, mas se for questão de manutenção do código, aí sim. Não tenho informações suficientes pra elaborar uma resposta, então deixo apenas como comentário mesmo.

Comment: Eu me lembro que views vão manter o plano de consulta armazenado, então não precisaria passar por essa fase novamente. Também é possível que o plano gerado no momento da criação da view seja mais eficiente do que um plano gerado na execução de uma query qualquer. Agora, se os dados sofrerem uma alteração muito grande, é provável que o plano de consulta da view se torne inadequado, tornando-a nesse caso lenta

Comment: Outro ponto que você deveria se perguntar é: eu preciso mesmo dessa performance extra? Porque se não, inserir essa view vai se assemelhar mais a uma gambiarra. Os casos mais comuns são os casos que o @RovannLinhalis falou, onde a query é feita sempre da mesma maneira.

Comment: Relacionado: [Is a view faster than a simple query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439056/is-a-view-faster-than-a-simple-query)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As views, comumente, são utilizadas para melhoria de segurança, evitar repetição de código SQL e semântica.

Na maioria dos casos não trará melhorias de perfomance, exceto se estiver falando de uma [Indexed View](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views). Nesse caso **poderia** haver um aumento de desempenho. Leia o trecho retirado da [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views):

> Criando um índice *clusterizado* único em uma view melhora a performance porque a view é guardada no banco de dados da mesma forma que um índice *clusterizado* é.

- [Qual é a diferença entre clustered index e nonclustered index?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198708/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-clustered-index-e-nonclustered-index)

A Microsoft disponibilizou um gráfico que mostra um ganho absurdo de performance com esse tipo de view:

[image]

Esse foi retirado de [Improving performance with SQL Server 2005 Indexed Views.](https://technet.microsoft.com/lIbrary/Cc917715)

- [Designing indexed views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864.aspx), da MSDN, pode ser uma boa leitura

Answer (score 3):

A `VIEW`, dentre outras coisas, serve para que você armazene uma query complexa em um objeto no banco, facilitando a reutilização desse código SQL. Então toda vez que ela é acionada o código SQL será executado.

Assumindo que utilize o SQL Server, você terá ganhos em desempenho se utilizar `Indexed Views`. Esse recurso permite que o SQL Server faça a busca dos dados nos índices criados para a view como se fosse uma tabela.

Existem algumas restrições que você pode encontrar na documentação da Microsoft. No link a seguir também está documentado como criar uma `Indexed View` https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views

O **PostgreSQL** e o **Oracle** também implementam algo parecido, porém com o nome de `Materialized View`. Abaixo alguns links sobre migração de `Materialized View` do Oracle para `Indexed Views` do SQL Server.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssma/2011/06/20/migrating-oracle-materialized-view-to-sql-server/

https://www.akadia.com/services/sqlsrv_matviews.html