# Consulta SQL muito lenta no banco OpenEdge, o que pode ser?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, odbc

Estou com dificuldades ao executar consultas no banco de dados OpenEdge 11.6.
Diversas consultas demoram muito para serem executadas, as vezes quase 2 minutos.

Segue um exemplo de consulta que estou tentando executar:

```
SELECT
docto_item.cod_fil,
count(*) qtd_item,
sum(docto_item.vlr_item_bruto) as vl_nota,
sum(docto_item.vlr_icms) as vl_icm,
sum(docto_item.vlr_pis),
sum(docto_item.vlr_cofins),
sum(docto_item.vlr_icms_subst) as vlr_icms_subst
FROM
pub.docto_item, pub.docto
WHERE

docto_item.cod_emp=1
AND docto_item.cod_fil=5
AND docto_item.tipo_ent_sai=0 --0 = Saida ou 1 = entrada
AND docto_item.dt_movto='2017-09-22'
AND docto.modulo='edi'
AND docto.cod_destino=docto_item.cod_destino
AND docto.cod_emp=docto_item.cod_emp
AND docto.cod_fil=docto_item.cod_fil
AND docto.num_docto=docto_item.num_docto
AND docto.serie_docto=docto_item.serie_docto
GROUP BY docto_item.cod_fil;
```

Sei que só olhando a consulta pode ficar difícil de saber o que pode ser.
Mas se houver alguém que tenha tido esse problema e conseguiu resolver, já seria muito bom.

Comment: Não conheço o OpenEdge mas veja o básico , índices , etc https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/index-function.html    https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmsrf/update-statistics.html

Comment: Algo que salta aos olhos é esse JOIN IMPLÍCITO: "FROM tab!, tabB". Embora funcione é DEPRECATED e por favor nunca escrevam nesse formato. O coitado que for dar manutenção nisso agradece

Answer (score 0):

Com base no comentário fiz algumas pesquisas e consegui encontrar a solução e deixo respondido para quem tiver o mesmo problema.

Informei na query a clausula `with(index(nome_do_indice))` mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT CAMPO
FROM TABELA T WITH (INDEX(UM_INDICE))
INNER JOIN OUTRA_TABELA OT
WITH (INDEX(OUTRO_INDICE))
ON OT.ID = T.ID
```

Referencia:
[Como utilizar um índice específico numa consulta em SQL Server?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/524/como-utilizar-um-%C3%ADndice-espec%C3%ADfico-numa-consulta-em-sql-server)

Comment: Nota , No Oracle o equivalente é o HINT